# Server-sent event error event

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, server-sent-events

Error event code :

```
source.onerror = function(e) {
        if (source.readyState != 0) {
        connectionClosed();
        console.log("Disconnected");
        }
};
```

it is working on firefox, but it does not reconnect automatically when the server is on.
it is not working on chrome, but it does reconnect automatically when the server is on.
source event initialization:

```
var source = new EventSource("http://s10/server.php");
```

server.php file in s10 server:

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        echo "data: hello \n\n";
        flush();
?>
```

I tried also this, and it's the same thing

```
source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        if (source.readyState != 0) {
            connectionClosed();
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Automatic reconnection [was not implemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=831392) in Firefox until Firefox 36.

And it works in Chromium as of 38 version.